# facebook php sdk - facebook login to my website success .. logout will log me out of facebook but not my website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

facebook php sdk - facebook login to my website success .. logout will log me out of facebook  but not my website

i don't know why ..

index.html

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>eNetwork | eShopping </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <title></title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


    <div class="topwrapper">
        <div class="topbar">
                <?php if ($user): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>"><img src="img/facebooklogout.png"  alt="Logout facebook" height="25px"></a>

                <?php else: ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>"><img src="img/facebooklogin.png"  alt="Use Facebook to Login" height="25px"></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ($user): ?>
                <?php echo "<strong>"."Welcome, ". $user_profile['name']."  |"."</strong>";?>
                <?php endif ?>
                <a href="#"><strong>My Account</strong></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="facebooklogo" src="img/facebooklogo.png" height="25px"> </a>
        </div><!-- .top-->
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">


        <header class="header">
            <img src="img/logo1.png"  height="80px"><hr> <br>
        </header><!-- .header-->






        <div class="middle">




            <div class="left-sidebar">
                <strong>Left Sidebar:</strong> <hr/> <br/>
            </div><!-- .left-sidebar -->

            <div class="content">
                <strong>Content:</strong> 


            </div><!-- .content -->

        </div><!-- .middle-->

    </div><!-- .wrapper -->

<footer class="footer">
    <strong>Footer:</strong> 
</footer><!-- .footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

facebook.php ................................................ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2011 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

require 'facebook-php/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'hidden for security issues',
  'secret' => 'hidden for security issues',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}



?>
```

what might be my problem?

because i copied the example file from facebook sdk  and reused it again :)

even the example didn't work .. what i need to change?

Comment: This behavior is normal .. logging out of application will Facebook session causing ending current application session :)

Comment: yes .. but my website didn't end of logout .. 
go to www.istiqama-way.com/eNetwork

Comment: and try to log in and log out .. and see what exactly I mean :)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

you can do it simply by doing the following:

In your page log out button or image:

```
<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
```

logout.php ------------------------------------------->

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';     //including the facebook php sdk
$facebook->destroySession();
header( "location:index.php" );
?>
```

when using `facebook=>getLogoutUrl();` <<<<< this makes your facebook.com logout ...